# Why has getUserMedia to be invoked through a server?

Tags: webrtc

I'm not sure I get how getUserMedia works fundamentally, when I invoked it through a static html page that I opened with Chrome, nothing happens and nothing is in the console. But if I invoke the page through a static node server that serves the html page, it all works.

Does anyone know why that is the case?

Comment: Its a restriction made by chrome for security purposes.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent oh I see, so there's no magic behind it but an implementation detail of Chrome?

Comment: That is the gist of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a security feature of Chrome not allowing getUserMedia (and others) on the `file://` protocol. You will have to install a local server. Or I think you can use the `--allow-file-access-from-file` [Chrome command line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).